# Webstorm/IntelliJ: Configure spaces (not tabs) to be wider/narrower

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation, webstorm

In IntelliJ/Webstorm, is there a way to have the editor indent by (e.g.) two spaces, but indented as if it were actually set to four spaces?

In other words: have it actually insert two space characters into the file, but display  them (e.g.) double-wide in the editor.

(**motivation:** comply with employer's 2-space-indent policy while simultaneously not having everything so crammed together)

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. Having a different size is tab's job. Not space. If you want a double sized space, look for some font alternatives that do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not currently possible; please vote for [IDEABKL-7126](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7126). But note that it can't be expected in near future - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-53596#comment=27-197416